# Splitting a string in Java when two delimiters are next to one another

Tags: java, regex, string, token

In java, I have a line that was read in by a `BufferedReader` called `str`. I also have a `String[]` called `splitStr` which will contains the contents of the string split on anything that is not an alphanumeric character and the character `'`.

The code looks like this:

```
// Assume str contains a line
String[] strSplit = str.split("[^a-zA-z0-9']|\\s");
```

Given the string `"Hello can't world, how are [you! (today)? "` which has been assigned to `str` I would expect the following contents in my `strSplit` array:

```
strSplit = [ "Hello", "can't", "world", "how", "are", "you", "today" ]
```

However, I end up getting this in my `strSplit` array:

```
strSplit = [ "Hello", "can't", "world", "", "are", "[you", "", "today" ]
```

Essentially, when splitting the string `"world, "` it recognizes the `world` part and the delimiter `,` and then since there is no valid string before another delimiter, it gives me an empty string `""`. Also for some reason a string with brackets `[]` will end up in the split string.

I'm assuming this has to do with the way I set up my regex but I'm not sure what I did wrong. I'm pretty new to regex things so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw you don't need the `|\\s`, `[^a-zA-z0-9']` includes that.

Comment: @ndn I originally tried it without `|\\s` however it still gave me the `""` as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex has a wrong range selection

```
[^a-zA-z0-9']|\\s
       ^           This should be uppercase,
```

otherwise it'll select all the characters whose ASCII value is between `A` and `z`.

[image: ASCII table of what characters are selected by A-z]

The range `[A-z]` will select all the characters as shown in the above image.

**Use `+` quantifier** both on the character class and space character.

```
str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+|\\s+");
                        ^    ^
```

This will select as many possible matches.

[**Regex101 Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aY7zD1/2)

Comment: Thank you! This works for the whitespaces. Any idea why the brackets `[]` aren't stripped out in the final string?

Answer (score 2):

```
str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+")
```

That didn't work??

Comment: This works for everything except for a newline character. My original mistake was that I had `A-z` instead of `A-Z`. However, I'm getting newlines as a `""` string

Comment: I checked newline character as well, and this is my output.

"Hello"
"can't"
"world"
"how"
"are"
"you"
"today"

Comment: Yes, the lowercase z was the problem. But since I hand-coded that, didn't face the issue..

Comment: Hmm.. my only guess is because I'm on a mac which I think has a `\r` character? But I'm definitely getting a `""` where any blank newline is.

Comment: Hmm, im on a mac too. String str = "Hello can't world, how\n are\n \n [you! (today)? ";

Comment: Produces an output of "Hello"
"can't"
"world"
"how"
"are"
"you"
"today"

Comment: Ah wait, now that I think about it, the `str` variable would be updated to just a blank line since `str` was from `readLine()`. So I guess I just have to add a check in there. I've been up for too long D: